# Stuck during installation Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop and it always freezes when I confirm how much the Ubuntu partition will have. Anyone encountered the same?

Comment: Does it happen when you do check for the Ubuntu partition size? I'm not getting your question. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered a similar issue when trying a relatively complex partitioning scheme involving encryption of more than one partition, I'm not sure if that's the case for you or not.

Regardless, one possible option which worked for me is to create the partitions in advance. For this:

1. Boot Ubuntu's live system
2. Run `gparted` - the graphic partition editor - and partition your disc any way you like. You can use `parted` or any other tool really.
3. If you need to set encryption or complex LVM you can do it at this stage
4. Start the installer (there's an icon on the desktop)
5. Choose the "Something else" option on the partitioning menu
6. You should see the partitions you've set up. For each partition, click it and then click `change` - then select the file system and/or mount point for that partition. Also, select whether to format the partition
7. Continue with the installation as usual

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me. It might also be possible to install the server distro and then sidegrade to the desktop version (the server install is console-only and works fine).